# Issues when submitting lsf jobs on mixed windows machines

Tags: windows, lsf

Have been facing the below problem for a long time on windows:

We have some machines of windows 10, 2012, 2016 and 2019.

1. Now, after submission of jobs via IBM lsf command (bsub) on all machines(of windows 10, 2016, 2019, 2012) from the submission host (windows 10) i.e. we trigger regressions on the submission host and the jobs are submitted then on all machines (of windows 10, 2016, 2019, 2012) via submission host, the banks do not run properly.
2. But, when submission of jobs via IBM lsf command (bsub) is done on only windows 10 machines via submission host, the banks run properly.
3. Also, when submission of jobs via IBM lsf command (bsub) is done on only windows 2012 & 2016 & 2019 machines together via submission host, the banks run properly.

In all, when we run regressions on the mixed cluster, we face a problem that test cases take a very very long time to complete or something gets stuck. Otherwise not.

What could be the cause of the issue? What can be done to solve this problem?

Thank You!

Comment: Any update on it?

Comment: This is not a development question, it belongs to another site, like https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @SimonMourier Any other community where this question can be posted. Didn't get any reply from the communities you mentioned above.

Comment: The fact you received no answer from there doesn't mean it's a development question.